# css fixed width tab emelents for ui li

Tags: css

I'm new to css, and I just encountered a problem. I have some tabs that are ul and li, and the number of these tabs vary, and I want them all to have the same width, but I dont want to give it myself, I want css to set the items equal size of width and spread them. how can I do this?

```
 $html[] = '<ul style=" background-color:#CCEEED"; class="nav nav-tabs" id="set-nn_tabs-' . $items['0']->set . '">';
    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        $html[] = '<li style="width: 25%; text-align:center"    class="' . trim('nn_tabs-tab ' . ($item->active ? 'active' : '') . ' ' . trim($item->class)) . '">';

        if ($item->haslink)
        {
            $html[] = $item->title_full;
            $html[] = '</li>';
            continue;
        }
```

Comment: I added that 25% myself, but I don't want to do it this way

Comment: are they displaying vertically or horizontally?

Comment: displaying horizontally

Comment: You can get close using display: table on the ul, and display: table-cell on the li's. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4L0myz94/)

But if you want to have them all to have the exact same width you may have to use JS and loop through them to find max width and then set the rest.

Comment: i used this, but it's not working on my code, and I can't figure out why

Comment: if you are still working on this try putting together a fiddle with your rendered html and we can then see whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

You should divide 100 by the size of your array (the number of tabs), and use it as width for each "li".

```
$width = 100 / count($items);
//now use $width in your style attribute.
```

Comment: actually I'm using this code in joomla, and this is for a module, so I use this in different pages, and the number of tabs vary in each

Comment: That's why you should rely on the "count" of your array.